# iOS Call Directory Extension,can't enable my demo App

Tags: ios

There is no enbale button .Settings->Phone->Call blocking & identification->Enable the App.
I run the same oc code to the iPhone6 and iPhone6P device.And the iPhone6 is OK,but the iPhone6P has no button to enable my demo app.